# Menu driven program to print other programs

Tags: python

I have written a code for a menu driven program but the menu doesn't print after I have typed in the code after that. Please help me with this!

Here is the code -

```
def mainMenu():
print("1. lst")
print("2. a")
print("3. quit")
while True:
    selection=int(input("Enter Choice: "))
if selection==1:
    lst()
elif selection==2:
    a()
elif selection==3:
    exit
else:
    print("Invalid choice. Enter 1-3")
    mainMenu()
    
def lst():
lst = []
num = int(input("How many numbers: "))
for n in range(num):
numbers = int(input("Enter the numbers"))
lst.append(numbers)
print("Maximum element in the list is :", max(lst), "\nMinimum element in the list is :", min(lst))
```

mainMenu()

```
def a():
a=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements"))
for i in range (1, n+1):
    b=int(input("Enter element:"))
    a.append(b)
    a.sort()
    print("Third largest element is:",a[n-3])`
```

mainMenu()

Comment: Put the line 2-4 inside your while, take out the calls for mainMenu(), now after completing the commands, the loop will be restarted and the menu will be reprinted

Comment: Give us a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your indents.

```py
def mainMenu():
    print("1. lst")
    print("2. a")
    print("3. quit")
    while True:
        selection=int(input("Enter Choice: "))
        if selection==1:
            lst()
        elif selection==2:
            a()
        elif selection==3:
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Enter 1-3")
            mainMenu()  # Also watch for recursion here
```

and your second part

```py
def lst():
   lst = []
   num = int(input("How many numbers: "))
   for n in range(num):
       numbers = int(input("Enter the numbers"))
       lst.append(numbers)
   print("Maximum element in the list is :", max(lst), "\nMinimum element in the list is :", min(lst))
```

Running the below code

```py
def lst():
   lst = []
   num = int(input("How many numbers: "))
   for n in range(num):
       numbers = int(input("Enter the numbers"))
       lst.append(numbers)
   print("Maximum element in the list is :", max(lst), "\nMinimum element in the list is :", min(lst))

def mainMenu():
    print("1. lst")
    print("2. a")
    print("3. quit")
    while True:
        selection=int(input("Enter Choice: "))
        if selection==1:
            lst()
        elif selection==2:
            a()
        elif selection==3:
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Enter 1-3")
            mainMenu()  # Also watch for recursion here

mainMenu()
```

creates this output

```
1. lst
2. a
3. quit
Enter Choice: 1
How many numbers: 5
Enter the numbers1
Enter the numbers2
Enter the numbers3
Enter the numbers4
Enter the numbers5
Maximum element in the list is : 5 
Minimum element in the list is : 1
Enter Choice: ^C
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did try to execute your code but it is giving me this error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/menu.py", line 25, in <module>
    mainMenu()
  File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/menu.py", line 16, in mainMenu
    lst()
  File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/menu.py", line 5, in lst
    numbers = int(input("Enter the numbers"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1 2 3 4 5 '

Comment: From the code you provided, I assumed that you just wanted to enter each number individually (since it was in a loop). If you want it so that you can bulk-add numbers, replace that line with `numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter the numbers").split(" ")))` and the line below is `lst += numbers`.